# Check a misspelled word in a list

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

I want to get the location name that is inside **datos** using the official list of cities that I have in a df.

```
barha = pd.read_csv('https://wms.ign.gob.ar/geoserver/bahra/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=bahra%3Alocalidad_bahra&outputFormat=csv')

datos = pd.DataFrame([['1','La Plata Buenos Aires'],['2','Lanús'],['3','lanus'],['4','Agua de Buenos Aires'],['5','mar del Plata'],['6','Gas SAN ISIDRO']],
columns = ['id', 'desc'])
```

I tried to do this

```
datos['localidad'] = datos['desc'].apply(lambda x: next(iter([i for i in barha['nombre_geografico'] if i in x]), None))
```

The expected result would be:

| id | desc | localidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | La Plata Buenos Aires | La Plata |
| 2 | Lanús | Lanús |
| 3 | lanus | Lanús |
| 4 | Agua de Buenos Aires | none |
| 5 | mar del Plata | Mar del Plata |
| 6 | SAN ISIDRO | San Isidro |

But the result I get is:

| id | desc | localidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | La Plata Buenos Aires | Pla |
| 2 | Lanús | Lanús |
| 3 | lanus | none |
| 4 | Agua de Buenos Aires | none |
| 5 | mar del Plata | Pla |
| 6 | SAN ISIDRO | none |

I know that it took the exact word, but how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `barha["nombre_geografico"].at[19]` is "Pla". Why do you expect to ignore this? That is the first match for "La Plata Buenos Aires".

Comment: but im not willing the first match, i looking for the coincidence (not exact one)

Comment: `if i in x` translates to `if "Pla" in "La Plata Buenos Aires"` which is `True`

Comment: ok cool i get it soo, i need to chance the code